# Creating a superclass SunPlanet for Sun and Planets using inheritance.

Tags: python, inheritance

My Class Program:

```
import turtle
import math

    class SunPlanet:
        def __init__(self,iname,irad,im):
            self.name = iname
            self.radius = irad
            self.mass = im
        def getMass(self):
           return self.mass

    class Sun(SunPlanet):
       def __init__(self, iname, irad, im, itemp):
           super().__init__(self,iname,irad,im)
           self.temp = itemp
           self.x = 0
           self.y = 0

           self.sturtle = turtle.Turtle()
           self.sturtle.shape("circle")
           self.sturtle.color("yellow")

       # other methods as before


       def __str__(self):
           return self.name

       def getXPos(self):
           return self.x

       def getYPos(self):
           return self.y


    class Planet(SunPlanet):
        def __init__(self, iname, irad, im, idist, ivx, ivy, ic):
            super().__init__(self,iname,irad,im)
            self.distance = idist
            self.x = idist
            self.y = 0
            self.velx = ivx
            self.vely = ivy
            self.color = ic.strip()

            self.pturtle = turtle.Turtle()

            self.pturtle.color(self.color)
            self.pturtle.shape("circle")

            self.pturtle.up()                    
            self.pturtle.goto(self.x,self.y)
            self.pturtle.down()        

        #other methods as before

        def getXPos(self):
            return self.x

        def getYPos(self):
            return self.y

        # animation methods
        def moveTo(self, newx, newy):
            self.x = newx
            self.y = newy
            self.pturtle.goto(newx, newy)

        def getXVel(self):
            return self.velx

        def getYVel(self):
            return self.vely

        def setXVel(self, newvx):
            self.velx = newvx

        def setYVel(self, newvy):
            self.vely = newvy



    class SolarSystem:
        def __init__(self, width, height):
            self.thesun = None
            self.planets = []
            self.ssturtle = turtle.Turtle()
            self.ssturtle.hideturtle()
            self.ssscreen = turtle.Screen()
            self.ssscreen.setworldcoordinates(-width/2.0,-height/2.0,width/2.0,height/2.0)

        def addPlanet(self, aplanet):
            self.planets.append(aplanet)

        def addSun(self, asun):
            self.thesun = asun

        def showSun(self):
            print(self.thesun)

        def showPlanets(self):
            for aplanet in self.planets:
                print(aplanet)

        def freeze(self):
            self.ssscreen.exitonclick()

            # animation methods
        def movePlanets(self):

            G = .1                
            dt = .001             

            for p in self.planets:                       
               p.moveTo(p.getXPos() + dt * p.getXVel(),   
                        p.getYPos() + dt * p.getYVel())   

               rx = self.thesun.getXPos() - p.getXPos()   
               ry = self.thesun.getYPos() - p.getYPos()
               r = math.sqrt(rx**2 + ry**2)               

               accx = G * self.thesun.getMass()*rx/r**3  
               accy = G * self.thesun.getMass()*ry/r**3  

               p.setXVel(p.getXVel() + dt * accx)   
               p.setYVel(p.getYVel() + dt * accy)
```

My Main Program:

```
ssInputStrings = []

inputPath = str(input("Please enter the source location for the solar system files: "))
startDate = datetime.datetime.now()

while True:
    endDate = datetime.datetime.now()
    delta = endDate - startDate

    # if the duration has been met, break out of the loop
    if delta.seconds > 10:
        break

    print(delta.seconds)

    # initialize switch
    addToCollection = True

    # read and store the content of each input file in the collection
    for file in os.listdir(inputPath):
        print(file)
        inputFilePath = inputPath  + file
        inputFile = open(inputFilePath, 'r')
        text = inputFile.read()
        inputFile.close()

        # get the first word from the input file which identifies the solar system object
        firstWordFromInputFile = text.split(",")

        # if the solar system object has already been stored in the collection,
        # do not store it again
        for string in ssInputStrings:
            firstWordFromInputString = string.split(",")
            if firstWordFromInputFile[0] == firstWordFromInputString[0]:
                addToCollection = False
                break
            else:
                addToCollection = True

        if addToCollection == True:
            ssInputStrings.append(text)

#        os.remove(inputFilePath)

    # pause the thread for one second (necessary otherwise cpu will spike up)
    time.sleep(1)

#----------------------------------------------------------
# Instantiate objects and run simulation
#----------------------------------------------------------
from ClassModule import *

def createSSandAnimate():
    ss = SolarSystem(2,2)  
    so = ""

   # sun
    for string in ssInputStrings:
       if string[0:3] == "SUN":
           so = string.split(",")


    sun = Sun(str(so[0]), int(so[1]), int(so[2]), int(so[3]))
#   sun = Sun("SUN", 5000, 10, 5800)
    ss.addSun(sun)
    for string in ssInputStrings:
       if string[0:7] == "MERCURY":
            so = string.split(",")
    m = Planet(str(so[0]), float(so[1]), int(so[2]), float(so[3]), int(so[4]), int(so[5]),str(so[6])  )
    #m = Planet("MERCURY", 19.5, 1000, .25, 0, 2, "blue")
    ss.addPlanet(m)

    for string in ssInputStrings:
       if string[0:5] == "EARTH":
            so = string.split(",")
    m= Planet(str(so[0]), float(so[1]), int(so[2]), float(so[3]), int(so[4]), float(so[5]),str(so[6]))
   #m = Planet("EARTH", 47.5, 5000, 0.3, 0, 2.0, "green")
    ss.addPlanet(m)

    for string in ssInputStrings:
       if string[0:4] == "MARS":
            so = string.split(",")
    m=Planet(str(so[0]), int(so[1]), int(so[2]), float(so[3]), int(so[4]), float(so[5]),str(so[6]))

   #m = Planet("MARS", 50, 9000, 0.5, 0, 1.63, "red")
    ss.addPlanet(m)

    for string in ssInputStrings:
       if string[0:7] == "JUPITER":
            so = string.split(",")
    m=Planet(str(so[0]), int(so[1]), int(so[2]), float(so[3]), int(so[4]), int(so[5]),str(so[6]))

    #m = Planet("JUPITER", 100, 49000, 0.7, 0, 1, "black")
    ss.addPlanet(m)

   #ss.showSun()
    ss.showPlanets()

    numTimePeriods = 2000                  
    for amove in range(numTimePeriods):
        ss.movePlanets()                  

    ss.freeze()

createSSandAnimate()
ssInputStrings = []

inputPath = str(input("Please enter the source location for the solar system files: "))
startDate = datetime.datetime.now()

while True:
    endDate = datetime.datetime.now()
    delta = endDate - startDate

    # if the duration has been met, break out of the loop
    if delta.seconds > 10:
        break

    print(delta.seconds)

    # initialize switch
    addToCollection = True

    # read and store the content of each input file in the collection
    for file in os.listdir(inputPath):
        print(file)
        inputFilePath = inputPath  + file
        inputFile = open(inputFilePath, 'r')
        text = inputFile.read()
        inputFile.close()

        # get the first word from the input file which identifies the solar system object
        firstWordFromInputFile = text.split(",")

        # if the solar system object has already been stored in the collection,
        # do not store it again
        for string in ssInputStrings:
            firstWordFromInputString = string.split(",")
            if firstWordFromInputFile[0] == firstWordFromInputString[0]:
                addToCollection = False
                break
            else:
                addToCollection = True

        if addToCollection == True:
            ssInputStrings.append(text)

#        os.remove(inputFilePath)

    # pause the thread for one second (necessary otherwise cpu will spike up)
    time.sleep(1)

#----------------------------------------------------------
# Instantiate objects and run simulation
#----------------------------------------------------------
from ClassModule import *

def createSSandAnimate():
    ss = SolarSystem(2,2)  
    so = ""

   # sun
    for string in ssInputStrings:
       if string[0:3] == "SUN":
           so = string.split(",")


    sun = Sun(str(so[0]), int(so[1]), int(so[2]), int(so[3]))
#   sun = Sun("SUN", 5000, 10, 5800)
    ss.addSun(sun)
    for string in ssInputStrings:
       if string[0:7] == "MERCURY":
            so = string.split(",")
    m = Planet(str(so[0]), float(so[1]), int(so[2]), float(so[3]), int(so[4]), int(so[5]),str(so[6])  )
    #m = Planet("MERCURY", 19.5, 1000, .25, 0, 2, "blue")
    ss.addPlanet(m)

    for string in ssInputStrings:
       if string[0:5] == "EARTH":
            so = string.split(",")
    m= Planet(str(so[0]), float(so[1]), int(so[2]), float(so[3]), int(so[4]), float(so[5]),str(so[6]))
   #m = Planet("EARTH", 47.5, 5000, 0.3, 0, 2.0, "green")
    ss.addPlanet(m)

    for string in ssInputStrings:
       if string[0:4] == "MARS":
            so = string.split(",")
    m=Planet(str(so[0]), int(so[1]), int(so[2]), float(so[3]), int(so[4]), float(so[5]),str(so[6]))

   #m = Planet("MARS", 50, 9000, 0.5, 0, 1.63, "red")
    ss.addPlanet(m)

    for string in ssInputStrings:
       if string[0:7] == "JUPITER":
            so = string.split(",")
    m=Planet(str(so[0]), int(so[1]), int(so[2]), float(so[3]), int(so[4]), int(so[5]),str(so[6]))

    #m = Planet("JUPITER", 100, 49000, 0.7, 0, 1, "black")
    ss.addPlanet(m)

   #ss.showSun()
    ss.showPlanets()

    numTimePeriods = 2000                  
    for amove in range(numTimePeriods):
        ss.movePlanets()                  

    ss.freeze()

createSSandAnimate()
```

[This is the link for the link for the error description.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TkO8o.jpg)

Please go through the class code and please help me out. I have been trying this from a week. I am not getting where i missed.

Comment: what part of "expects 4 arguments, 5 given" are you not understanding?

Comment: The error message is pretty straight forward. Also what's with all the getters and setters? Those are completely unnecessary in Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Addressing only the error, [`super()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super) isn't being called correctly.  Change it to:

```
super(Sun, self).__init__(iname, irad, im)
```

And later:

```
super(Planet, self).__init__(iname, irad, im)
```

If you want others to go over your code, this probably isn't the best place.  Consider posting to [codereview.stackexchange.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead.